# getting error Could not find stored procedure 'sp_configure'. in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I need to change degree of parallelism, but when i run that i am getting error

```
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_configure'.
```

Here is my script for that

```
USE test;  
GO   
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 8;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;  
GO
```

Comment: Ok, then how can we resolve this problem ?

Comment: Ok, let me try this

Comment: I used master and getting this error 'USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.'

Comment: If you wanz to configure the Single DB and not the Server, you have to use Alter Database.

Comment: @Nikolaus I am new in sql server, so i am not aware with this thing, i want to run query in parrallel

Comment: If you want to configure the server you‘d better comment out the use Statement and change the Connection in SSMS to master.

Comment: @RyanWilson...I've tested, and I can run OP's query perfectly fine.

Comment: No offense but should you be messing with this if you have to ask? Do you understand the wider implications of changing such a configuration?

Comment: thanks to all it is working now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are using Azure SQL Database where `sp_configure` is not available. Use [ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CCONFIGURATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql) instead to configure `MAXDOP`.

Comment: Yes i am using Azure server